# picking out objects in json file not working javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using the Discord API and I want it to send the longitude and latitude of the ISS using the "where the ISS at" API, but if I try and pick an object out of the JSON it comes back empty.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix} were is the iss`)) {
  const https = require('https');

  https.get('https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {

      console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
      const {
        lattitude,
        longitude
      } = data;
      console.log(lattitude)
      console.log(longitude)
      message.channel.send(`ok  ${data}`)
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like as of now you are trying to pick out *latitude* and *longitude* from the **string** data. You are parsing it to JSON but not reassigning it, as **JSON.parse** does not parse in place. You can find more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Here is what you should be doing-:

```
const {latitude, longitude} = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

- is your data a JS object when you destruct?
- spell latitude correctly
- there is no `explanation` in a valid response:

```js
{
  "name": "iss",
  "id": 25544,
  "latitude": -48.568896551266,
  "longitude": 153.94349230508,
  "altitude": 436.29840426652,
  "velocity": 27536.388032323,
  "visibility": "eclipsed",
  "footprint": 4589.4699866736,
  "timestamp": 1592575515,
  "daynum": 2459020.0869792,
  "solar_lat": 23.430766332023,
  "solar_lon": 329.0668493775,
  "units": "kilometers"
}
```

Working code using fetch

```js
fetch('https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const {
      latitude,
      longitude
    } = data;
    console.log(latitude)
    console.log(longitude)
  });
```